# joining 2 tables with specific conditions

Tags: join, merge, macros, sas

I have 2 tables. First is original and contains row_number and several fields.

row_num col1 col2
1 a b
2 c d
3 e f

Second table is areport from first table, which shows type of mistake, col_name and row number:

m_id field row_num
m1 col1 1
m1 col1 3
m2 col2 2

And my task is to join to 2nd table the values of each field in table 1 depending on row_num and column, should be smth like:

m_id field row_num value
m1 col1 1 a
m1 col1 3 e
m2 col2 2 d

I've tryed using varios transposes like using by and id arguments, but i understand that it would be easier to use macro.

```
proc sort data=a1;
by row_num;
run;
proc transpose data=a1 out=a2;
by row_num;
var m_id;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge the (sorted) sets and use VVALUEX() to programmatically get the (character) value of a variable by name.

Something like:

```
data combined;
  merge first second;
  by row_num;
  value = vvaluex(field);
  keep m_id field row_num value;
run;
```

This assumes that row_num is unique in the first set.